# Moodle installation in xampp: version 5.5.31 is required and you are running 5.5.5.10.1.21

Tags: xampp, moodle

I just install moodle on xampp and get report:

> version 5.5.31 is required and you are running 5.5.5.10.1.21

i already install newest xampp version, and already try to change mysqli to mariadb in config.php, but still not working. any sugest regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit your config.php and specify database as "mariadb" instead of "mysqli"

Answer (score 0):

Select Mariadb as your database instead of MySQL during installation.You wont be able to turn back to database selection but i suggest you to delete and create a fresh install.